# EeeeeK! What happened to my privilieges?

Tags: support, privileges

As you can see from a previous post from [Jin](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/), [Design for Drupal Answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/491/design-for-drupal-answers), once Jin has completed the new theme that is used for Drupal Answers, we will get out of the beta phase.

The most important thing that changes is the minimum reputation required for most of the privileges.
The most important changes are the following ones:

```
Privilege                   Reputation in beta phase     Reputation after beta phase
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create tags                        150                          300
Retag questions                    200                          500
View close votes                   250                         1000
Cast close and reopen votes        500                         3000
Edit questions and answers        1000                         2000
Create tag synonyms               1250                         2500
Approve tag wiki edits            1500                         5000
Access to moderator tools         2000                        10000 
Protect questions                 3500                        15000
Trusted user                      4000                        20000
```

These changes don't influence the moderator users, who are considered trusted users with more privileges, independently from their reputation.

This means, for example, that more than 50 users will not be anymore able to vote to close questions (until they reach a reputation of 3000), and 15 users will not be able to create tags synonyms (until they reach a reputation of 2500), and only 4 users will be able to access the moderator tools. (Other users will be able to access the moderator tools once they become 10k users.)

Comment: I think the biggest bummer are the number of users that lost question/answer editing privileges...

Comment: I think the biggest bummer is the number of users that lost the privilege of voting for closing questions.

Comment: I agree with both, more with @kiamlaluno as edits only take one person, but at least there are workarounds for each problem (moderator/privileged member action)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that If a user is already above the normal threshold for a given privilege at the time of the switchover, that privilege is retained. On the other hand, if a user has a given privilege during beta, but not enough for the normal threshold for said privilege, said privilege will be lost at switchover. The privilege will need to be earned again by reaching the normal threshold.